# How to find $E[X^2]$ when computing the variance?

Tags: probability

Putting $X_i$ to be the result of the $i$-th dice roll out of 420 rolls, I have found that $E[S]=420\cdot 3.5$, where $S$ is the sum of the $420$ rolls. Trying to compute the variance, I am having troubles finding $E[S^2]$. When finding $E[S]$ I could use the linearity of the expected value, but here I can't possibly do so, for this isn't a regular sum, but a sum raised by 2(if this is how it's said. My English is poor.).
I would really appreciate any approach of help.

Following the expected value rules: $E[S^2]=\sum_{i=1}^{420}X_i^2$ but I still get that my variance is less then $-2000$ whereas in the answers it is **positive**. Where have it gone wrong?

Comment: Note that your expression for $E[S^2]$ is not correct, and we can get the variance without that from 420$\mathrm{Var(X_i)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variance is linear since the rolls are independent, but the variance is  $[E(S^2)] - [E(S)]^2$.  The variance for 1 die is
$$
\mathrm{Var(X_i)} = (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2)/6 - 3.5^2
$$
$$
\mathrm{Var(S)} = 420\mathrm{Var(X_i)} = 1225
$$
$$
[E(S^2)] = 1225 + [420(3.5)]^2 =  2162125
$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $Var(X) = EX^2 - (EX)^2$, you can obtain $ EX^2 = Var(X) + (EX)^2$

Comment: But I look for $EX^2$ because I want to compute the variance.